# TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python

I'm that guy who had an problem with a calculator.thanks to Joran Beasley 
I've got my problem better.But now i have this problem.

Code:a part was

```
intery.config(intery+intery2)
print(su)
```

now its:

```
def su():
int(Entery.get())
```

New Error:

```
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I'll be happy if Mr.Beasley Will help me.

Comment: This doesn't look like java.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're calling a method (`get`) on a class (`Entery`). That's not working because the method expects to be called on an instance of the class, rather than the class itself.

I don't know enough about your program to guess where you should be creating the instance, but here's the general idea:

```
# somewhere in your code:
entery = Entery() # maybe pass some args?

# later
def su():
    return int(entery.get()) # call on the saved instance
```

I'd added a `return` to your function, as otherwise you'd be converting the return value of `get()` to an `int` and then immediately throwing that integer away. I suppose you might choose to do something else with it, but again, I don't know enough about your code to guess.